# Issue reading a variable JSON in Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, error-handling, azure-data-factory

My pipeline receives the Path and the name of a JSON file.

This is part of the flow that I created:

[image]

The lookup step is used to read the JSON File and later I need to get a very specific value using this formula in the set variable step:

```
@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Information.Area.AreaName}
```

This is an small example of part of the file:

```
{
  .....
  "Information": {
    "Area": {
      "AreaName": "General",
      "Workers":[
       ......
       ]
   }
}
```

But sometimes, I can get only this:

```
{
  .....
  "Information": null
}
```

With the first example I do not have any problem, but with the second I'm getting troubles because the value does not exist.  My question is, how to avoid the error if the information that  I need is not present? Something similar to the lax mode in sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use in a single step using a similar logic, set as below value in dynamic value.

```
@if(equals(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Information,null),'null',activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Information.Area.AreaName)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need the null to be without quotes @IpsitaDash-MT in order to match the OP's file?  I could only get it to work this way.  I've updated the post, hope that's ok.  Upvote from me.

Comment: Thanks very much @wBob for the update :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a hack for that...

Try to use an `if` when setting the variable.

Here is a pipeline created with three steps to show how this could work:

[image]

**1. Lookup:** read the json as you did.

**2. FirstRow**: set a variable with the content of the first row.

`@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow}`

**3. Area**: test if the variable contains "AreaName" and only if TRUE assign the AreaName to the variable.

`if(contains(variables('FirstRow'), 'Area'),activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Information.Area.AreaName, null)`

Reference:
https://endjin.com/blog/2021/02/how-to-safely-reference-a-nullable-activity-output-in-synapse-pipelines-and-azure-data-factory

Answer (score 0):

Here a cleaner approach:

`@coalesce(activity('Lookup1').output?.firstRow?.Information, 'null')`

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/coalescefunction) `coalesce`: Evaluates a list of expressions and returns the first non-null (or non-empty for string) expression.

And putting `?` (safe-null operator) returns null if there is not `firstRow` or `Information` in the dot notation, check [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables).

[image]

There are also more complex queries, [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions):

> The below example shows a complex example that references a deep
> sub-field of activity output. To reference a pipeline parameter that
> evaluates to a sub-field, use [] syntax instead of dot(.) operator (as
> in case of subfield1 and subfield2), as part of an activity output.
>
> ````
> @activity('*activityName*').output.*subfield1*.*subfield2*[pipeline().parameters.*subfield3*].*subfield4* ```
> ````